# SpringBoot application stuck at springboot logo when running and web browser not run (LOCAL)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have spring boot application, and when I try to run that application it just stucks at Spring boot logo and nothing happens after that like error or bug.

[this view when I running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAgj9.png)

[and this view of local running port 8440](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FXUq.png)

(sorry I entered the wrong image earlier) and this error in web browser

so if i meet with this error, do I Enable TLS 1.2 on my computer (windows 10 ) or not ?

and this code from logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLING-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/data/logs/spv/system.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} [%thread] - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/data/logs/spv/system.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="BATCH-ROLLING-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/data/logs/spv/batch.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/data/logs/spv/batch.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="SQL-ROLLING-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/data/logs/spv/sql.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/data/logs/spv/sql.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="error" additivity="false">
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING-FILE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.overo.batch" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="BATCH-ROLLING-FILE" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="com.overo.dao" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SQL-ROLLING-FILE" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="com.overo" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING-FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING-FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Any guess how can I debug this issue ?

Comment: you have port 8443 on screenshoot and expect 8440 in question description

Comment: I entered the wrong image earlier. and it happened in my browser (chrome).
do i enable TLS on my computer or u have other fix problem for my error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enter the correct URL in the browser:

```
https://localhost:8440
```

That's what the browser is complaining about

Comment: oh thanks Simon Martinelli, it works and i can work again.
but i have question. why i should to enter the correct 
```https://localhost:8440```

but in other demo_app just 
```https://localhost:{portYouUse}```
it can run ? I'm just learning in spring boot framework. and this is for my training where I work now

Comment: Because you don't have a forward from http to https on your local machine. That's what website mostly do

Comment: sorry I just accepted your answer earlier. this firts time to me. thank you so much